# Одр: кровать или лошадь?

Tags: этимология

Одром высокопарно называют ложе (особенно, смертное), но одновременно и старую клячу. Почему так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет. Старая кляча это *одёр*. С беглой гласной Ё - нет одра, дать одру... 
Возможно именно эта совершенно несвойственная для Ё беглость и послужила причиной смешения этого слова с "одр". Фасмер, правда, даёт форму "одр" и для лошади, а для ложа - народный вариант "одёр", но, видимо, исключительно для обоснования родственности слов.

Родственность эта спорна.
Одёр (лошадь) - от драть, ободрать (в смысле - на живодёрню пора),
Одр (ложе) - древнейшее индоевропейское, с исходным значением "настил вокруг столба, дерева". Возможно родственно с деревом. Связь с "драть" тоже возможна, но менее вероятна.

~~~
Спасибо за хороший вопрос.

Answer (score -1):

**Одр** - это  постель, носилки больного или старого человека, тело которого плохо пахнет или попросту воняет, т. е. источает запах или дух (устаревшее). Причины этого: залежалое - не стиранное белье, немытое тело, возможно запах разлагающейся плоти, язв и т. п. Каждый, кто был в морге, не забудет тошнотворного запаха трупа.
На латыни запах =  odor. Вспомните слово дез**одор**ант.

Кстати, у охотников есть метод охоты на медведей, который включает в себя  устройство особого схорона - лежака на дереве (где прячется охотник), который также называется одор. Для приманивания медведя используется труп коровы.

Comment: Вообще-то в исходном значении ни о каком запахе, тем более о старом человеке, вообще нет и речи..